# selected index in dropdown list throwing error when no value is selected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the values selected from a dropdown list and populate in a row of a table . I am using:

```
cell2.innerHTML = choiceInput.options[choiceInput.selectedIndex].text;
```

where `choiceInput` is the name of my dropdown element.

This works if I select an option from the dropdown, but if I do not select anything from the dropdown, I get a `null` value selected and get a JavaScript error.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Get the potential `option` element, the use an *if-statement* so that you don't try to access `.text` when no element is available.

```
var selected = choiceInput.options[choiceInput.selectedIndex];

if (selected)
    cell2.innerHTML = selected.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Validation.

```
function validateListBox(){
var listBoxSelection=document.getElementById("choiceInput").value;
if(listBoxSelection==0){
alert("Please select );
return false;
}else{
return true;
}
return true;
}
```